# MATLAB Access Violation crash What in the code could cause this

Tags: java, matlab, crash, batch-processing, crash-reports

I've got a simple batch file that goes as follows

```
for  %%G in (*.txt) do (
    matlab /wait /nosplash /minimize /nodesktop /r "script1('%%~dpnxG')";quit 
    start "" /b /wait /separate proc_eng_track.exe "%%~dpnG" 
    matlab /wait /nosplash /minimize /nodesktop /r "script2('%%~dpnG')";quit    
)
```

which basically calls a couple of MATLAB scripts and call a small program in between them
The MATLAB scripts work just fine when I test them, the scripts works fine for a while but them MATLAB crashes at a different file each time
judging from when the crash occurs I am guessing it occurs during script2 I have no idea why though, Looking through the MATLAB crash dump file  i see that Access violation  is detected i can't make out anything else any help would be appreciated

Here are the scripts for both functions

**Script2**

```
function script2(Input)

Folders=strfind(Input,'\');
Foldername=Input(Folders(end-1)+1:Folders(end)-1);
dir = Input(1:max(strfind(Input,'\')));
% if isempty(dir)
%     dir = '.\';
% end
InFile=[Input '.rat'];
OutFile=[dir Foldername '.out'];
M=dlmread(InFile);
duration=length(M)/100; %in seconds
No_Syllables=sum(M);
Speech_rate=No_Syllables/duration;
 if ~exist(OutFile,'file')
    dlmwrite(OutFile,Speech_rate);
  else
    dlmwrite(OutFile,Speech_rate,'-append');
 end
end
```

**Script1**

```
function script1(Input)
Out=Input(1:end-3);
Output=[Out 'e19'];
fileID=fopen(Input);
C=textscan(fileID,'%f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f     %f','delimiter',' ','MultipleDelimsAsOne',1,'HeaderLines',2);
C(1)=[]; %delete first column
C_abs=exp(cell2mat(C)/10);
fclose(fileID);
dlmwrite(Output,C_abs,'delimiter',',');
```

Finally the MATLAB crash dump file 
Hope it's helpful

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------
          Access violation detected at Thu Oct 31 17:26:03 2013
------------------------------------------------------------------------

Configuration:
  Crash Decoding     : Disabled
  Default Encoding   : windows-1252
  MATLAB Architecture: win64
  MATLAB Root        : C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2013b
  MATLAB Version     : 8.2.0.701 (R2013b)
  Operating System   : Microsoft Windows 7
  Processor ID       : x86 Family 6 Model 58 Stepping 9, GenuineIntel
  Virtual Machine    : Java 1.7.0_11-b21 with Oracle Corporation Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM mixed mode
  Window System      : Version 6.1 (Build 7601: Service Pack 1)

Fault Count: 1


Abnormal termination:
Access violation

Register State (from fault):
  RAX = 000000001e7c8910  RBX = 0000000064284190
  RCX = 0000000004025288  RDX = 00000000040253e7
  RSP = 00000000040251d0  RBP = 00000000040253e7
  RSI = 0000000004025288  RDI = 0000000000000000

   R8 = 0000000000000000   R9 = 0000000064874140
  R10 = 00000000040253c0  R11 = 00000000040251c0
  R12 = 0000000000000001  R13 = 0000000000000000
  R14 = 0000000000000000  R15 = 0000000000000000

  RIP = 000000006eec3df9  EFL = 00010206

   CS = 0033   FS = 0053   GS = 002b

Stack Trace (from fault):
[  0] 0x000000006eec3df9 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2013b\bin\win64\mpath.dll+00081401 mpPath::copy+00064905
[  1] 0x000000006eec3e33 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2013b\bin\win64\mpath.dll+00081459 mpPath::copy+00064963
[  2] 0x000000006eec3e69 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2013b\bin\win64\mpath.dll+00081513 mpPath::copy+00065017
[  3] 0x000000006eec3e33 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2013b\bin\win64\mpath.dll+00081459 mpPath::copy+00064963
[  4] 0x000000006eec4349 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2013b\bin\win64\mpath.dll+00082761 mpPath::copy+00066265
[  5] 0x000000006eec471a C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2013b\bin\win64\mpath.dll+00083738 mpPath::copy+00067242
[  6] 0x000000006eec5d5f C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2013b\bin\win64\mpath.dll+00089439 mpWritePathToCacheFile+00002495
[  7] 0x000000006eecd94c C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2013b\bin\win64\mpath.dll+00121164 mpDir::copy+00023196
[  8] 0x000000006eeccb7a C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2013b\bin\win64\mpath.dll+00117626 mpDir::copy+00019658
[  9] 0x000000006eecd57f C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2013b\bin\win64\mpath.dll+00120191 mpDir::copy+00022223
[ 10] 0x000000006eecd9e6 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2013b\bin\win64\mpath.dll+00121318 mpDir::copy+00023350
[ 11] 0x000000006eeccb7a C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2013b\bin\win64\mpath.dll+00117626 mpDir::copy+00019658
[ 12] 0x000000006eecd57f C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2013b\bin\win64\mpath.dll+00120191 mpDir::copy+00022223
[ 13] 0x000000006eecd9e6 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2013b\bin\win64\mpath.dll+00121318 mpDir::copy+00023350
[ 14] 0x000000006eeccb7a C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2013b\bin\win64\mpath.dll+00117626 mpDir::copy+00019658
[ 15] 0x000000006eecd57f C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2013b\bin\win64\mpath.dll+00120191 mpDir::copy+00022223
[ 16] 0x000000006eecd9e6 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2013b\bin\win64\mpath.dll+00121318 mpDir::copy+00023350
[ 17] 0x000000006eeccb7a C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2013b\bin\win64\mpath.dll+00117626 mpDir::copy+00019658
[ 18] 0x000000006eeba840 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2013b\bin\win64\mpath.dll+00043072 mpPath::copy+00026576
[ 19] 0x000000006eebaaca C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2013b\bin\win64\mpath.dll+00043722 mpPath::copy+00027226
[ 20] 0x000000006eebae16 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2013b\bin\win64\mpath.dll+00044566 mpPath::copy+00028070
[ 21] 0x000000006eed07f8 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2013b\bin\win64\mpath.dll+00133112 mpReplacePath+00000088
[ 22] 0x000000018001f318 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2013b\bin\win64\m_dispatcher.dll+00127768 Mpathctx::~Mpathctx+00000680
[ 23] 0x000000018001da9a C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2013b\bin\win64\m_dispatcher.dll+00121498 mdLoadModuleForPackageOrClass+00000986
[ 24] 0x000000018001dbed C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2013b\bin\win64\m_dispatcher.dll+00121837 mdLoadModuleForPackageOrClass+00001325
[ 25] 0x000000018000d7ff C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2013b\bin\win64\m_dispatcher.dll+00055295 Mfh_file::dispatch_fh+00001167
[ 26] 0x000000018000ddb7 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2013b\bin\win64\m_dispatcher.dll+00056759 Mfunction_handle::dispatch+00000487
[ 27] 0x0000000004ea6a81 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2013b\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+00486017 inFunctionHandleInterface::DestroyWorkspace+00308737
[ 28] 0x0000000004f30657 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2013b\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+01050199 inEachVisibleName+00015383
[ 29] 0x0000000004ea46c2 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2013b\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+00476866 inFunctionHandleInterface::DestroyWorkspace+00299586
[ 30] 0x0000000004e8b85f C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2013b\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+00374879 inFunctionHandleInterface::DestroyWorkspace+00197599
[ 31] 0x0000000004e8b7c8 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2013b\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+00374728 inFunctionHandleInterface::DestroyWorkspace+00197448
[ 32] 0x0000000004eaebbd C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2013b\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+00519101 inFunctionHandleInterface::DestroyWorkspace+00341821
[ 33] 0x0000000004eab5cc C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2013b\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+00505292 inFunctionHandleInterface::DestroyWorkspace+00328012
[ 34] 0x0000000004e8e529 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2013b\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+00386345 inFunctionHandleInterface::DestroyWorkspace+00209065
[ 35] 0x000000018000d612 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2013b\bin\win64\m_dispatcher.dll+00054802 Mfh_file::dispatch_fh+00000674
[ 36] 0x000000018000defa C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2013b\bin\win64\m_dispatcher.dll+00057082 Mfunction_handle::dispatch+00000810
[ 37] 0x0000000004ea6a81 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2013b\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+00486017 inFunctionHandleInterface::DestroyWorkspace+00308737
[ 38] 0x0000000004f1e805 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2013b\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+00976901 inGetCurrentWS+00001301
[ 39] 0x0000000004ea45e1 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2013b\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+00476641 inFunctionHandleInterface::DestroyWorkspace+00299361
[ 40] 0x0000000004e8b85f C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2013b\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+00374879 inFunctionHandleInterface::DestroyWorkspace+00197599
[ 41] 0x0000000004e8b7c8 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2013b\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+00374728 inFunctionHandleInterface::DestroyWorkspace+00197448
[ 42] 0x0000000004f22835 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2013b\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+00993333 inPushCheckpoint+00000997
[ 43] 0x0000000004f15847 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2013b\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+00940103 MathWorks::MException::MExceptionEnvelope::MCOSClassID+00016167
[ 44] 0x0000000004f52db5 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2013b\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+01191349 inEvalCmd+00009045
[ 45] 0x0000000004f52d82 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2013b\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+01191298 inEvalCmd+00008994
[ 46] 0x0000000004f27646 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2013b\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+01013318 inGetEcho+00000310
[ 47] 0x0000000004f1fbfb C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2013b\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+00982011 inGetCurrentWS+00006411
[ 48] 0x0000000004f49779 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2013b\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+01152889 inInitializeParser+00001225
[ 49] 0x0000000004f497fc C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2013b\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+01153020 inInitializeParser+00001356
[ 50] 0x0000000004f49851 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2013b\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+01153105 inEvalCmdWithLocalReturn+00000065
[ 51] 0x0000000004f50a3c C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2013b\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+01182268 inReclaimMemoryPools+00000060
[ 52] 0x000000006e4f2464   C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2013b\bin\win64\mcr.dll+00140388 mcr_initialize_main+00009268
[ 53] 0x000000006e522051   C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2013b\bin\win64\mcr.dll+00335953 mnRunPathDependentInitialization+00000065
[ 54] 0x000000006e50bcbd   C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2013b\bin\win64\mcr.dll+00244925 mcrInstance::init_on_interpreter_thread+00000861
[ 55] 0x000000006e50edf9   C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2013b\bin\win64\mcr.dll+00257529 mcr_get_mcr+00004585
[ 56] 0x000000006e4e44b0   C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2013b\bin\win64\mcr.dll+00083120 mcr::runtime::setInterpreterThreadToCurrent+00029472
[ 57] 0x000000006e4e4510   C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2013b\bin\win64\mcr.dll+00083216 mcr::runtime::setInterpreterThreadToCurrent+00029568
[ 58] 0x000000006b01fa96   C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2013b\bin\win64\uiw.dll+00391830 UIW_IsUserMessage+00000086
[ 59] 0x000000006b020175   C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2013b\bin\win64\uiw.dll+00393589 UIW_SetGLIMUserMsg+00000117
[ 60] 0x000000006b0201f9   C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2013b\bin\win64\uiw.dll+00393721 UIW_SetGLIMUserMsg+00000249
[ 61] 0x00000000774b87fe                     C:\Windows\system32\USER32.dll+00165886 GetMenuBarInfo+00000638
[ 62] 0x000000007749f5fb                     C:\Windows\system32\USER32.dll+00062971 SystemParametersInfoW+00000235
[ 63] 0x00000000774a4895                     C:\Windows\system32\USER32.dll+00084117 IsProcessDPIAware+00000465
[ 64] 0x00000000777011f5                      C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll+00332277 KiUserCallbackDispatcher+00000031
[ 65] 0x00000000774a908a                     C:\Windows\system32\USER32.dll+00102538 PeekMessageW+00000186
[ 66] 0x00000000774a50fe                     C:\Windows\system32\USER32.dll+00086270 GetKeyState+00000238
[ 67] 0x00000000774a3a6f                     C:\Windows\system32\USER32.dll+00080495 PeekMessageA+00000087
[ 68] 0x000000006aff94db   C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2013b\bin\win64\uiw.dll+00234715 UIW_SetCurrentDialog+00000731
[ 69] 0x000000006b021632   C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2013b\bin\win64\uiw.dll+00398898 ws_FreeSystemFont+00000482
[ 70] 0x000000006f156600 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2013b\bin\win64\libmwservices.dll+01009152 services::system_events::PpeDispatchHook::~PpeDispatchHook+00055552
[ 71] 0x000000006f156fc5 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2013b\bin\win64\libmwservices.dll+01011653 services::system_events::PpeDispatchHook::~PpeDispatchHook+00058053
[ 72] 0x000000006f157e10 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2013b\bin\win64\libmwservices.dll+01015312 services::system_events::PpeDispatchHook::~PpeDispatchHook+00061712
[ 73] 0x000000006f160596 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2013b\bin\win64\libmwservices.dll+01050006 sysq::removeProcessPendingEventsHook+00010998
[ 74] 0x000000006f16089a C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2013b\bin\win64\libmwservices.dll+01050778 svWS_ProcessPendingEvents+00000138
[ 75] 0x000000006e4e552d   C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2013b\bin\win64\mcr.dll+00087341 mcr::runtime::setInterpreterThreadToCurrent+00033693
[ 76] 0x000000006e4e57fb   C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2013b\bin\win64\mcr.dll+00088059 mcr::runtime::setInterpreterThreadToCurrent+00034411
[ 77] 0x000000006e4d9545   C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2013b\bin\win64\mcr.dll+00038213 mcrInstantiationError::operator=+00003221
[ 78] 0x000000006e4dc872   C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2013b\bin\win64\mcr.dll+00051314 mcr_invoke_on_interpreter_thread+00001602
[ 79] 0x000000006e4e98e6   C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2013b\bin\win64\mcr.dll+00104678 mcrDesktopMain+00000230
[ 80] 0x0000000140004f0b C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2013b\bin\win64\MATLAB.exe+00020235
[ 81] 0x0000000140006a07 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2013b\bin\win64\MATLAB.exe+00027143
[ 82] 0x00000000775a652d                   C:\Windows\system32\kernel32.dll+00091437 BaseThreadInitThunk+00000013
[ 83] 0x00000000776dc541                      C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll+00181569 RtlUserThreadStart+00000033


If this problem is reproducible, please submit a Service Request via:
    http://www.mathworks.com/support/contact_us/

A technical support engineer might contact you with further information.

Thank you for your help.
```

**The java dump file**

```
Operating System: Microsoft Windows 7
  Processor ID:     x86 Family 6 Model 58 Stepping 9, GenuineIntel
  Host Name:        EE250880
Stack Trace:
[  0] 0x000000006f96dba4 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2013b\bin\win64\libmwfl.dll+00056228 fl::diag::stacktrace_base::rend+00000612
[  1] 0x000000006f96e0ce C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2013b\bin\win64\libmwfl.dll+00057550 fl::diag::stacktrace_base::stacktrace_base+00000030
[  2] 0x000000000429ad87 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2013b\bin\win64\libut.dll+00109959 utDumpStackTrace+00000487
[  3] 0x000000006b7c1f32   C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2013b\bin\win64\jmi.dll+00270130 LoadJAWTLibrary+00015538
[  4] 0x000000005ac10aed C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2013b\sys\java\jre\win64\jre\bin\server\jvm.dll+02165485 JVM_FindSignal+00002525
[  5] 0x000000005ac03c29 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2013b\sys\java\jre\win64\jre\bin\server\jvm.dll+02112553 JVM_ResolveClass+00461817
[  6] 0x000000005ac15a3e C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2013b\sys\java\jre\win64\jre\bin\server\jvm.dll+02185790 JVM_FindSignal+00022830
[  7] 0x000000005aeedc2f C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2013b\sys\java\jre\win64\jre\bin\server\jvm.dll+05168175 JVM_FindSignal+03005215
[  8] 0x00000000750312e3 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2013b\bin\win64\MSVCR100.dll+00463587 _C_specific_handler+00000151
[  9] 0x000000005aeed349 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2013b\sys\java\jre\win64\jre\bin\server\jvm.dll+05165897 JVM_FindSignal+03002937
[ 10] 0x00000000776d9d2d                      C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll+00171309 RtlDecodePointer+00000173
[ 11] 0x00000000776c91cf                      C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll+00102863 RtlUnwindEx+00003007
[ 12] 0x0000000077701248                      C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll+00332360 KiUserExceptionDispatcher+00000046
[ 13] 0x000000005aaf22fa C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2013b\sys\java\jre\win64\jre\bin\server\jvm.dll+00991994
[ 14] 0x000000005aaf258b C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2013b\sys\java\jre\win64\jre\bin\server\jvm.dll+00992651
[ 15] 0x000000005aaddf63 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2013b\sys\java\jre\win64\jre\bin\server\jvm.dll+00909155
[ 16] 0x000000005aade132 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2013b\sys\java\jre\win64\jre\bin\server\jvm.dll+00909618
[ 17] 0x000000005ab
------------------------------------------------------------------------
        Fatal Java Exception detected at Thu Oct 31 17:43:51 2013
------------------------------------------------------------------------

Configuration:
  Crash Decoding     : Disabled
  Default Encoding   : windows-1252
  MATLAB Architecture: win64
  MATLAB Root        : C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2013b
  MATLAB Version     : 8.2.0.701 (R2013b)
  Operating System   : Microsoft Windows 7
  Processor ID       : x86 Family 6 Model 58 Stepping 9, GenuineIntel
  Virtual Machine    : Java 1.7.0_11-b21 with Oracle Corporation Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM mixed mode
  Window System      : Version 6.1 (Build 7601: Service Pack 1)

Java 1.7.0_11-b21 with Oracle Corporation Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM mixed mode
```

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?